# SWT Java: Rectangular Selection over Image on Canvas without rapid repaint

Tags: java, swt

I have an image on a canvas:

```
    canvas = new Canvas(top, SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.NO_REDRAW_RESIZE);
    GridData canvasGridData = new GridData(GridData.VERTICAL_ALIGN_FILL);
    canvasGridData.verticalSpan = 15;
    canvasGridData.horizontalAlignment = GridData.FILL;
    canvasGridData.verticalAlignment = GridData.FILL;
    canvasGridData.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = true;
    canvasGridData.grabExcessVerticalSpace = true;
    canvas.setLayoutData(canvasGridData);
    canvas.addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {
        public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {
            if (buttonPressed) {
                GC gc = e.gc;
                image = GetMyImagetoDisplay();
                gc.drawImage(image, 10, 10);
            }
        }
    });
```

When a GUI button is pressed, reDraw() is called and image is loaded.

I also have a mouse events for getting a rectangular selection.  They draw a rectangular selection over the image:
        canvas.addListener(SWT.MouseDown, new Listener() {

```
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
            startX = event.x;
            startY = event.y;

            drag = true;
        }
    });

    canvas.addListener(SWT.MouseUp, new Listener() {

        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
            endX = event.x;
            endY = event.y;

            drag = false;

            canvas.redraw();
        }
    });

    canvas.addListener(SWT.MouseMove, new Listener() {

        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event) {


            if(drag)
            {
                endX = event.x;
                endY = event.y;


                canvas.redraw();
            }
        }
    });

    canvas.addListener(SWT.Paint, new Listener() {

        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
            if(drag)
            {
                GC gc = event.gc;

                //gc.setBackground(top.getDefault().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_BLACK));
                gc.setAlpha(128);

                int minX = Math.min(startX, endX);
                int minY = Math.min(startY, endY);

                int maxX = Math.max(startX, endX);
                int maxY = Math.max(startY, endY);

                int width = maxX - minX;
                int height = maxY - minY;

                gc.fillRectangle(minX, minY, width, height);
            }
        }
    });
```

The problem is, that the image keeps flickering as I drag the mouse across.

Can you suggest a fix?

Update:

By passing SWT.DOUBLE_BUFFERED to the Canvas constructor, it enabled double buffering!!!

```
imageCanvas = new Canvas(top, SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.NO_REDRAW_RESIZE | SWT.DOUBLE_BUFFERED);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're adding two `SWT.Paint` listeners to the same `Canvas` and they are competing against each other.

Your first listener paints the "background" and the second one paints the "foreground". The flickering you see is most likely the two of them painting alternatingly.

Consider something like this with just one paint listener:

```
canvas.addListener(SWT.Paint, new Listener() {
    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event event)
    {
        // paint background

        if(drag)
        {
            // paint foreground
        }
    }
});
```

---

If this doesn't change anything, try using `SWT.DOUBLE_BUFFERED` as the style of the `Canvas`.

Comment: Just a note to say this code more of less runs on my Mac, but the Mac defaults to double buffered so is probably dealing with the flickering and two paint listeners. I did have to reinstate the background color set in the second paint listener.

Comment: Good point - I have merged the two listeners.  Unfortunately it still flickers.  It must be because I add the image on every mouse move.  I may need to overlay a widget over it to handle the rectangle selection

Comment: @Baz No - I thought that was just for animation type effects but I will take a look

Comment: @Baz You were right!  Edit your answer with that and I will accept yours as it is only fair as you suggested it in a comment

Answer (score 0):

To answer to this was very simple!!!  By passing SWT.DOUBLE_BUFFERED to the Canvas constructor, it enabled double buffering!!!

```
imageCanvas = new Canvas(top, SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.NO_REDRAW_RESIZE | SWT.DOUBLE_BUFFERED);
```

This completely removed the flicker effect

Comment: @Baz Yep - I have accepted you answer now - thanks gain :)